# Send/ Read Data via USB between Win and Linux

Tags: python, linux, windows-10, usb

i want to send from my Python Programm (running on Windows 10) Data via USB Cable to another Pythonprogram running on a Linux PC.

The USB Link Cable (Model: Datalink Easy Copy) is detected correctly, but its not shown in the Windows Device Manager as COM Port.

Does anyone knows what to do?

Thanks!

Tested it with Surface and Windows Desktop PC and Surface and Linux PC.

Comment: Is it detected correctly on the Linux computer?

Answer (score 0):

You could use PyUSB for that, first install it `pip install pyusb` then use a script like the one below, dont forget to replace the vendor ID and product ID with the one you have.

```
import usb.core
import usb.util

# Find the USB device
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x1234, idProduct=0x5678)

# Claim the USB interface
interface = 0
usb.util.claim_interface(dev, interface)

# Receive data over USB
data = dev.read(1, 1024)

# Release the USB interface
usb.util.release_interface(dev, interface)

# Print the received data
print(data)
```